# Question regarding the proof that every non-negative measurable function is the limit of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f$ be a non-negative measurable function. For each $x$ define $k_n(x)$ to be the unique integer satisfying $$k_n(x)\leq 2^nf(x)<k_n(x)+1$$ Define $$s_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{k_n(x)}{2^n},\text{ if }f(x)<n
\\n,\text{ if }f(x)\geq n\end{cases}$$

Then $(s_n)$ is the required sequence of simple functions. This is done in every proof I've seen. Now is there any reason to assign them the value $n$ when $f(x)\geq n$? I understand that $k_n=2^nn$ when $f(x)=n$ so it seems like the natural choice. But the proof still works if we define $s_n(x)$ to be $0$ if $f(x)\geq n$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $s_n$ to be a simple function it needs to take on only finitely many values. A natural choice is to just use the dyadic numbers. We first fix $n$ and consider all numbers of the form $\{\frac{j}{2^n}\leq n: j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, this is a finite set. So we choose $s_n$ to only take values from this set and require that $s_n(x)\leq f(x)$. In addition to choosing $n$ so that $s_n$ only takes a finite number of values, there is an obvious connection between $s_n$ and $n$ that makes it easy to recognize.

The reason why you do not set $s_n(x) = 0$ if $f(x) > n$ is because $f$ can take values at $\infty$. Consider the measurable function $f =\infty$. Your idea would imply that $s_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$. But then $s_n(x)\not\to f(x)$ anywhere.

Comment: I see now. I assumed $f$ to be only real-valued. This proof would work for even extended real-valued functions. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why we choose $\frac{j}{2^n}$ instead of $\frac{j}{n}$?

Comment: @IntegralLover Either should work. Occasionally we need to work with series and in those cases we'd prefer $\frac{j}{2^n}$